# visual c++ ifstream to read files and assigned to variable

Tags: c++, ifstream

I was trying to read an input file by ifstream in vc++. The format of the file is as follows (2 column only but big file):

```
text1 \tab text2
and so on...
eof
```

I am trying to read text1 and text2 and if I find text2 is equal to the value of my String variable that I got from user input then I would assign a variable to text1 and do something.

Can anyone please give hints on how to code this? I have been trying with some c++ codes to integrated with my visual c++ but somehow I have lots of problems including conversion from std::string to String^.

I can do this easily with shell scripts but I want to learn how to do it with vc++.

I am very new with visual c++, please excuse my lack of knowledge.
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Show us whatever code you have and we'll go from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily store strings from file to any string variable using `sstream` and `istringstream` I think this piece of code might help

```
string string1,ch;
ifstream file("filename");
while(getline(file,ch);   //true while ch not equal to end of file.
    {
          istringstream ss(ch);    //will read lines and stores in ss.
          ss>>string1;         //copy read string in string1
     }
```

you need to `#include<sstream>`  to do the above.

Comment: Thanks, but then I won't be able to compare my variable of type System::String with std:string such as in the "if" statement "if ( var1 == var2) {". How can I read the file and store variables using String^?

Comment: Did u read String in Microsoft developer network. if u don't please read link is 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177218.aspx